# Feed the dog without bowl

Tags: dogs, health, feeding

My dog eats too fast, so I'm afraid of him getting some stomachal problem or choking. So I spread his food through the backyard's floor. This way, he eats one piece at time  and gets busy by sniffing around to find the food.

I'm concerned about the risks of he getting some bacteria. I drop the food far from places where he urinates and poops.

Is it risky?

Comment: what type of feed do you give him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your location in the world what parasites and diseases are to be found so I will be mentioning the ones in my area of Canada as examples.

First things that come to mind when allowing a dog to eat from the ground outside is:

- [Internal parasites](https://www.animalhealth.bayer.ca/en/dogs/all/#conditions)
- [Leptospirosis](http://www.merckvetmanual.com/generalized-conditions/leptospirosis/leptospirosis-in-dogs)

If your dog isn't regularly treated for worms and has some he will be re-contaminating himself by eating kibble near his feces or from other animals feces. If he eats any slugs/snails or feces from these invertebrates there is a possibility of catching [fox lungworm](https://www.animalhealth.bayer.ca/en/dogs/fox-lungworm/).

Leptospirosis is obtained from drinking urine of infected animals (foxes, raccoons, squirrels) or contaminated water sources like puddles. This disease is zoonotic (transmittable to people) but preventable through vaccination of your pet.

Risks are low for him to catch something in your back yard unless there's high volume of critters and other pets running through, that being said I'm sure he'd love a foraging toy!

Pet stores have MANY cool foraging toys to slow down his eating and make him use his brain! Some examples:

- [Kong Genius Mike](http://www.petexpertise.com/images/detailed/2/kong-genius-mike-puzzle-dog-toy.jpg)
- [Omega Paw Tricky Treat Ball](https://jefferspet-weblinc.netdna-ssl.com/product_images/tricky-treat-ball/53972050535a8f4a86000576/zoom.jpg?c=1402413138)
- [Dog treat fighter](http://insights.dice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Nina-Ottosson-Wooden-Dog-Treat-Fighter.png)
- [Green interactive dog feeder](https://www.companyofanimals.co.uk/sites/default/files/styles/compressed/public/pvi-green-slow-feeder-05.png?itok=6JoV_DQI)

These are some of the MANY products that will slow down his eating and make him work for his food in a cleaner environment.

Comment: I bought a very cool toy at the supermarket: https://images.bitcao.com.br/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/1200x/df033fa5f03140a266d22c4c479e59c4/p/e/pet_ball.jpeg
It has three levels of difficulty. I set it up on level 3. In ten minutes, my dog takes 10 minutes to eat all food, but it's fine. Before that, he would eat in 1 minute. However the food still drops on the floor, but I can hang it in somewhere that's clean, so the food will always drop in a secure place.

Answer (score 3):

You could try and feed him with the bowl, but only let him have a mouth full then take it away. Then repeat. Positive reinforcement for good behavior.  It'll take time tome and consistency.